# Laravel generate css from scss I can't see changes

Tags: css, laravel, sass

I have project in made Laravel. In scss file I've made changes (font-size and color) but I don't know how the css file is generated. Because I can't see changes in css file.
In Laravel documentation I see that css is generated in this way: `mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');`
but I don't know how to run this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed `node` and `npm` in your machine and already run below command

```
npm install
```

Then you need to follow two step.

**Step-1**:In your project root folder,there is file name `wbpack.mix.js` or `your/project/dir/wbpack.mix.js` and you may edit this file as you want

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

**Step-2:** After editing this file, you need to run this command

```
npm run dev
```

with this command compiling would be start and after ending,you may reload your browser to see the changes. `cntrl+F5` for fresh loading.

Otherwise download `node` & install it,npm will came over with `node`. And run first command and follow those two step.

**Tip**: if you changes your `scss` file or `js` constanly for the time being, you may run this command

```
npm run watch
```

Because,if you have changes in your `scss` and `js` file,you need to run over and over `npm run dev` to recompile your code.But if you have run `npm run watch`, it will automatically recompile,whenever you hit `cntrl+s`.

Answer (score 1):

Before compiling your CSS, install your project's frontend dependencies using the [Node package manager (NPM)](https://github.com/laravel/docs/blob/6.x/docs/%7B%7Bversion%7D%7D/mix):

```sh
npm install
```

Once the dependencies have been installed using `npm install`, you can compile your SASS files to plain CSS using Laravel Mix. The `npm run dev` command will process the instructions in your `webpack.mix.js` file.

```sh
npm run dev
```